# Proof of topology involving Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Question: Let X and Y be Hausdorff spaces. Give X X Y the product topology. Then X X Y is a Hausdorff space.

[image]

This is what I did, can someone verify this and let me know if I am correct or wrong? Also, kindly let me know if my proof need some changes or modifications due to bad notations.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your post. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: More simply, if $U_1, U_2$ are disjoint then $U_1\times Y$ and $U_2\times Y$ are disjoint nbhds of $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ respectively.

Comment: Why did you delete this question with my answer on it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571016/ ?

Comment: I am so sorry, I tried to delete the other one and accidentally deleted this one. My  Apologies!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got it.  A couple small things.  You reversed $x_i$ and $U_i$ when you chose disjoint $U_i$ containing the $x_i$.

Secondly, the notation for the null set is $\emptyset$, or $\{\}$.

Finally, taking one last peek, you might want to write out the word "and" instead of writing $\land$ in what is basically an English sentence.

I think the substance of your proof is correct.

Comment: I used to write "And" instead of using that symbol, but later I found that my prof prefers the symbol instead of "And", that's why I didn't use that. I will change the notation. But, i didnt follow wat u said at the begining.

Comment: You reversed $x_i$ and $U_i$ when you chose disjoint $U_i$ containing the $x_i$. What should i do?

Comment: You wrote $\exists U_1$ in $x_1$ and $U_2$ in $x_2$.  Isn't that backwards?  The point is that, by Hausdorffness, there exist disjoint $U_1,U_2$, with $x_1\in U_1$ and $x_2\in U_2$.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun As an additional comment: you "choose $V_1$, $V_2$ such that $y_1 \in V_1$, $y_2 \in V_2$" There is no need to introduce more sets , just use the product open sets  $U_1 \times Y$, $U_2 \times Y$ and be done with it. So *you* choose $V_1=V_2=Y$. The first coordinate already forces disjointness of the sets.

Comment: ok got it, cool. thanks a lot for the help.